# how to deal with DLL function with output parameter as Char** in VB

Tags: vb.net

we have c++ dll file with this API

```vb
BOOL GetPaths(TCHAR **Paths)
{ 
    //write data into paths
}
```

we will get out put in **paths, how to call and get output from vb.net.

VB.net code:

```vb
Public Shared Function GetPaths(<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, 
ArraySubType:=UnmanagedType.LPStr)><InAttribute(), Out()> ByVal strarr() As String) As Boolean


Dim sbs As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder(256)

Dim strArr = New String() {""}

GetDevicePaths(strArr)

Console.WriteLine(strArr(0).ToString)
```

output : Instead of full string am getting first element only

Comment: `TCHAR` may be `char` or it may be `wchar` depending on whether `UNICODE` is defined when the library is built.  The behavior you have looks like what would happen if it's actually wide chars but you're interpreting as narrow chars.  What happens if you marshal as `UnmanagedType.LPWStr`?

Comment: thanks @Craig i changed UnmanagedType.LPStr to UnmanagedType.LPWStr it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

`TCHAR` may be `char` or it may be `wchar` depending on whether `UNICODE` is defined when the library is built.  For typical ASCII alphanumeric characters, the wide version is two bytes with the same code as ASCII in the first byte and `0` in the second byte.  Thus, "output : Instead of full string am getting first element only" looks like the library was built as unicode, so that `TCHAR` is `wchar`, and you're interpreting it as narraw `char`.

To fix this, change your `MarshalAs` attribute to `UnamangedType.LPWstr`.